# Android API 31 App Icon on Splash Screen too small

Tags: android-studio, splash-screen, appicon, android-api-31

I have configured the API 31 (for Android 12) splash screen, using the Android Studio built-in image asset creator.

I have the app icon and branding image showing when the app comes up. However, the app icon on the splash screen is very small. Its original size is 1024pxx1024px, so nothing too tiny to begin with.
I tried to Resize its scaling to 120% - it did not do anything - see the below image:

[image]

What am I missing? what to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Android studio built in image generator. But you can https://icon.kitchen/ for generating your app icons and all. It works great I prefer this.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this nice tool, was not aware. Still, this isn't related to my problem with the app icon on the SPLASH screen being too small